# Dynamically change path of an image in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Hi all I am new to WPF, I have used a list view to render as grid view. I have a image column for which I set a value by binding the path. Now the problem is I need to change the path of the image based on a condition. If the condition is true I need the path of the image to be different. If false I change it to another path. Can this be done row by row? Below is my listview. Please Help

```
<ListView Name="LstGrd" Margin="0,105,0,138">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView  >
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Address" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Address}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" City" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=City}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" State" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=State}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" PostalCode" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PostalCode}" />
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Width="16" Name="Test" Height="16" Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Status"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your issue properly, you want to change the image if some condition changes.  I created a dummy version of the class you are binding to your listview, and added a property called "IsSelected" to show this.

```
<ListView Name="LstGrd" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView  >
            <GridViewColumn Header="">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" Address" Width="250" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Address}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" City" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=City}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" State" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=State}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header=" PostalCode" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PostalCode}" />
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Width="16" Name="Test" Height="16" Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Status"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Path=ImagePath2}" TargetName="Test" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The thing to notice here is that I added a column (this is optional - I just did so to make it easier to demonstrate).  Then, in your Image column, you need to add a `DataTrigger` to your `DataTemplate` to handle that property change.

Here is just the DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="16" Name="Test" Height="16" Source="{Binding Path=ImagePath,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
         <TextBlock Text="Status"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Source" 
                    Value="{Binding Path=ImagePath2}" 
                    TargetName="Test" />
         </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

This has the advantage over a Converter because it is a XAML only implementation.

Comment: the condition changes only after binding to the grid.i.e i check the condition only after binding a image by default to the grid.Will this work in this scenario(change image row by row based on condition).Sorry if i sound stupid am new to this.

Comment: What each GridViewColumn definitionis doing is controlling how a specific cell in a specific row is being displayed.  You are showing THIS Name, THIS Address, etc.  In the case of the DataTemplate, you are controlling how THIS piece of data is shown in this cell (namely, you are showing the ImagePath defined for this instance of your "Contact" class).  What the DataTrigger is doing is checking another property of this instance, and replacing the image with ImagePath2 for just this instance.  So, yes, it will change it row by row, based on that condition.

Comment: sorry to trouble you i have another question  when is the Datatrigger called.Is it only during databinding..Or put in this way i need to change the image on button click how can data trriger be implemented in that scenario.Thanks for your help

Comment: Here's what I would do.  Add two new properties to your Contact class, and implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.100).aspx) interface on that class (this is a very important interface to WPF.  Google it.  Understand it.  Love it.).  One of the properties is to hold the path to the new image (ImagePath2 in the example above).  The other property will be set when you handle your button click....(continued)

Comment: ....If you implement INotifyChanged properly, the WPF system will let anybody that is bound to that property know that it needs to use the new value.  That includes in the DataTrigger above.  So, to answer the question, it will happen automatically (assuming you set everything up properly).

Comment: It Worked man.You are Awesome.INotifyPropertyChanged did the trick...Thanks a million

Comment: Instead of using a trigger i updated the image source to a different path.It works like a charm

Comment: @karthi - glad that worked for you.  I went with the DataTrigger because that is more the "WPF" way.  As you get more into WPF, you will most likely move away from event-based programming, and more towards using an MVVM framework.  Don't worry if this doesn't make sense now, but file it away in your brain for later.  Good luck!

Comment: Sure!! it thought WPF was just all about design and they are similar to winform :-( ... Can you please point me some tutorials if you can.Thanks again

Comment: It can be, but one power of MVVM is a strong data binding system.  [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) is one from one of the experts on MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a converter:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path = ImagePath, Mode = TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource imageToValidatedImageConv}}" />
```

Where imageToValidatedImageConv is a resource defined as: `<local:ImageToValidatedImageConverter x:Key="imageToValidatedImageConv" />`

and your converter a class like:

```
public class ImageToValidatedImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if()
            {
                //return image1 
            }
            else
            {
                //return image2
            }

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new Exception("Cant convert back");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can this be implemented if i have to change the image on a button click.Please guide

Comment: Not sure if i follow what you pretend. The IValueConverter Interface provides you a way to apply custom logic to a binding. If you plan to change the image based on a button event click you can do it as you would normally do

Comment: Can you please show me how to change image inside a listview on a button click or point me out to some articles.Thanks for your help